# How to enable maintenance mode

Tags: python, fastapi

So I'm building a mobile app, and the backend is made with FastAPI.

Let's say I want to run maintenance for an hour or so.  Or in other words, any user's request should return the same thing, like a message and time for when everything is back to normal.

What would be the best way to achieve this scenario?

Comment: If you're running this through Apache or nginx or something similar in production, then the best place to put maintenance messages would be _there_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a middleware for that:

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def maintainence_mode(request: Request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    if MAINTAINENCE_MODE:
       return { "error" : "Sorry try later please" }
    return response
```